# Performance of the String searching algorithm

Tags: java, performance, time-limit-exceeded

I am trying to solve a string matching question mentioned [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/625/problem/B). I recently learned the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm and tried to implement it to solve this question. But I am getting a TLE for this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Gogl {
    static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyScannergogl sc=new MyScannergogl();//used own input function
        String text=sc.next();
        String pattern=sc.next();
        KMP(text,pattern);

            System.out.println(count);



    }
    static int[] computeTempArray(String pattern)
    {
        int lsp[]=new int[pattern.length()];
        int index=0;
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<pattern.length();)
        {
            if(pattern.charAt(i)==pattern.charAt(index))
            {
                lsp[i]=lsp[index]+1;
                i++;
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(index!=0)
                {
                    index=lsp[i-1];
                }
                else
                {
                    lsp[i]=0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return lsp;
    }
    public static void KMP(String text,String pat)
    {
        int lsp[]=computeTempArray(pat);
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while(i<text.length() )
        {

            if(text.charAt(i)==pat.charAt(j))
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(j!=0)
                {
                    j=lsp[j-1];
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if(j==pat.length())
            {
                count++;
                j=0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I couldn't understand where am I wrong. Whether I have not properly implemented the algorithm or is there some other problem I am not aware of. As I know that KNP is really fast so should have crossed the time limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<pattern.length();)
    {
        if(pattern.charAt(i)==pattern.charAt(index))
        {
            lsp[i]=lsp[index]+1;
            i++;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(index!=0)
            {
                index=lsp[i-1];
            }
            else
            {
                lsp[i]=0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

That's a while loop. There's no need to use `for` here.

```
    int i = 1;
    while(i<pattern.length())
    {
        if(pattern.charAt(i)==pattern.charAt(index))
        {
            lsp[i]=lsp[index]+1;
            i++;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(index!=0)
            {
                index=lsp[i-1];
            }
            else
            {
                lsp[i]=0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

You might want to use more descriptive variables in your code, because I have the hardest time trying to understand what `lsp` is. The `i` and `j` variables aren't helping either: are you traversing two collections? In what way?

Your class names are weird, what does `Gogl` mean?

More descriptive variables and classnames will help you when you view your code at a later point in time. If you don't feel like explaining the algorithm in code, at least put the name of the algorithm together with a link as a comment in the code.